# How many machines are broken?

Tags: probability, statistics

The question: Consider a company that manufactures toaster ovens. Let the probability that a toaster oven has a scratch be p = 0.01. Assume that different ovens get scratched independently. In one day, the company makes 100 ovens. Find the probability that 5 or more ovens get scratched.

My approach to this question: 
Let X be a random variable denoting the number of scratched ovens

$$P(X \ge 5) = (.01)^5(1)^{95} $$
The first factor comes from the probability that 5 of them are scratched, the second factor is 1 because we don't care if the rest of them are scratched. We only care that there are are at least 5 of them, which is guaranteed by the first factor.

However, according to the solution manuel,
$$P(X \ge 5) = \sum_{i=5}^{100}(.01)^i(.99)^{100-i} = .00343...$$

I'm not sure why my approach doesn't produce the same answer, since I guarantee that 5 of the ovens are scratched and for the rest of the ovens it doesn't matter whether they're scratched or not(Probability of either scratched or not = 1)

Comment: $(0.01)^5(1)^{95}$ is the probability that *very specifically* the first, second, third, fourth, and fifth toaster ovens are scratched, while the remaining 95 toaster ovens can be either. The solution you write from the solution manual is *also* incorrect (*and evaluates to about$3*10^{-11}$*) and is the probability that there are at least five scratched toaster ovens but they all *very specifically* appear at the front of the line ahead of all unscratched ovens.  The correct answer should instead be $\sum\limits_{i=5}^{100}\color{red}{\binom{100}{i}}(0.01)^i(0.99)^{100-i}\approx 0.00343\dots$

Comment: The point being, it could have been that the first five toasters were all fine and it was the sixth, twentieth, fourty-second, and nintieth through the hundredth toasters which were scratched.  We do not require that the scratched toasters appear at the front of the line, they could have been interspersed throughout the whole batch, and your answer does not account for that.  You accounted for some but not all of the possibilities.  For more info on the corrected approach from the solution manual, read about the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

Comment: Ah. That makes sense! Thank you for taking the time to respond!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I think the answer to be problem should actually be:

$$\sum_{i = 5}^{100} {{n} \choose {k}}(.01)^i (.99)^{100-i} \approx .0034 $$

You can interpret this as the probability of only five machines breaking plus only the probability that only six machines break plus only plus ... plus the probability that all the machines break. This covers all the possibilities of machines breaking such that there are at least 5 machines that break.

The probability you thought was:

Pick a specific five and have those be broken. What is the probability of that? Although that does guarantee that we have 5 broken toasters, what about the probability that a different five are broken and the rest are not? Your probability doesn't seem to account for that.